# Enums, Classes, Reflection, and Generic Casting

Tags: java, reflection, casting, enums, type-safety

Consider that I have an interface `com.mycompany.SomeInterface`, and an enum `com.mycompany.SomeEnum implements SomeInterface`. I want to get all enum constants of this class – as instances of `SomeInterface` – at runtime using the Reflection API.

Currently, my code (in the class `EnumConstantGetter`) is something like this:

```
Class<?> clazz = EnumConstantGetter.class.getClassLoader().
  loadClass("com.mycompany.SomeEnum");

if (!(SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    throw new Exception("the class doesn't implement SomeInterface");
}

if (!(clazz.isEnum()) {
    throw new Exception("not an enum");
} 

Class<? extends Enum<? extends SomeInterface>> castClass =
  (Class<? extends Enum<? extends SomeInterface>>) clazz; // cast #1
ArrayList<SomeInterface> vals = new ArrayList<SomeInterface>();
for (Enum<? extends SomeInterface> enumConstant :
  castClass.getEnumConstants()) {
    vals.add((SomeInterface) enumConstant); // cast #2
}
```

The above code appears to work, but I get a compiler warning at the creation of `castClass`.

My question, then, is: are both casts noted in the code (the cast on the class and the cast on the constant) necessarily valid based on my checks?

In other words, is every member of `Enum<? extends T>` guaranteed to implement `T`?

If the answer is, "Yes, the casts are safe," then why does the compiler give me this warning?

If not, why not? or, in what circumstances could the routine fail?

**EDIT:** As my code above is apparently confusing, here's my explanation of what's *supposed* to be happening:

1. Load the class named `SomeEnum` in the package `com.mycompany` and store its `Class` object in a variable.
2. Ensure that the referenced class implements the `SomeInterface` interface.
3. Ensure that the referenced class is an enum.
4. As we know that it's an enum implementing `SomeInterface`, cast it to a `Class<? extends Enum<? extends SomeInterface>>` **– cast #1**
5. Loop through all the enum constants.
6. For each constant, cast it to a `SomeInterface` **– cast #2 –** and add it to the list of constants.

Thanks!

Comment: `<? extends T>` implies that the class implements interface T.  Generally if you're using generics and type parameters properly, there should be no need to cast.  I have no idea what's going on in your code.  It looks awfully complicated, tho... However, if you have a for loop that expects to iterate over a group of objects that implement an interface, you should just use this:  `for (SomeInterface si : getList())`.  That's kinda the point of using interfaces. One of the main reasons to use generics (in my opinion) is to avoid casting completely.

Comment: In general, yes, generics avoid casting. However, because of type erasure, the types are erased at runtime. The [loadClass(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) method provides an instance of `Class<?>` - even if *I* know the class, Java doesn't. Since the `Class<T>` [getEnumConstants()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) returns a `T[]`, invoking it on a `Class<?>` gives a `?[]` (or `Object[]`) which *does* need to be cast.

Comment: In addition, `SomeClass<T extends SomeInterface>` does not necessarily implement `T` (consider an ArrayList of ListCellRenderers - the list itself isn't a renderer). My question is specifically regarding the `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` class.

Comment: Sorry... I probably shouldn't have even commented.  Please disregard my comment.  However, I don't see the relation between your most recent comment and my comment.  I don't really follow your code at all: it's quite a mouthful to read and I have not spent more than a few seconds trying to read it (like I said, I shouldn't have even bothered with my original comment).  Best of luck!

Comment: Is it not possible to do `for (SomeInterface i : castClass.getEnumConstants())`?  It seems that should be valid and should eliminate the need to cast inside the loop.  I will go away once you explain that this is not valid/possible ;)

Comment: I think Paul's answer enforces with what I was trying to say: if you know the class implements an interface, you can just refer to the objects in the array returned by _getEnumConstants()_ as if they **ARE** that interface. His answer is great because it takes advantage of this fact AND it captures the result in an array (that can be checked for null).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
Class<?> clazz = ...;
Class<? extends SomeInterface> someInterfaceClass;
try {
    someInterfaceClass = clazz.asSubclass(SomeInterface.class);
}
catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Specified type doesn't implement SomeInterface", cce);
}
SomeInterface[] enumConstants = someInterfaceClass.getEnumConstants();
if (enumConstants == null) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Specified type is not an enum.");
}

//use constants
```

This avoids the warnings because [`asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) is checked and [`getEnumConstants`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) returns `null` if the `Class` object "does not represent an enum type".

Comment: Thanks! That `asSubclass` method is what I was looking for.